# How to render matplotlib window in template page(html page) in plone

Tags: python, html, matplotlib, plone

I want to know how to render matplotlib window into template page in plone. Somebody explained me to render **matplotlib window as image** in plone site using the syntax which I mentioned below.

```
 <metal:main fill-slot="main">
     <div class="matplotwindow">
         <img src="" tal:attributes="src python:context.absolute_url()+'/@@classname'">
     </div>
 </metal:main>
```

But I need to know, is it possible to render **matplotlib window** into template page(html page). If anybody have an idea regarding this, please help me to do this and all.

Comment: Does *matplotlib window* imply interactive window (with zoom, and pan)?

Comment: yes.. But don't want (with zoom)..

Comment: If you don't want the zoom and pan features why not embedding a static image?

Comment: If you want to just display an image, you might as well use the `savefig()` function from matplotlib, to a folder and serve that out as a static image. Incase you want a more interactive one, have a look at [matplotlib webAgg](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_webagg.py)

Comment: I mentioned that i don't want as a static image...

Answer (score 1):

If you want interactivity, the simplest way is probably to integrate using a service like [plot.ly](https://plot.ly/)

Another option could be to use [Vincent](https://github.com/wrobstory/vincent) to generate a JSON file that is compatible with a D3.js visualization grammar called [vega](http://trifacta.github.io/vega/) or to directly output your data using the vega grammar.